# Publish site via visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, c#-5.0

I try to publish a site to: http://lolacyclingclub.org/ , but I get this error:

```
Error   2   Copying file bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml failed. Could not find file 'bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml'.     0   0   Lolabike
```

What exactly you have to do?

I found something that I have to delete the bin folder? Is that correct because it seems strange?

I see now this error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Web Server at lolacyclingclub.org

I dont know this error. has it to do read/write permissions? Or something like that?

Comment: here is a walk through on deploying a web application [Msdn deploy a web app walk through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1y1404zt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Try publishing the website to some folder in your computer and then upload the files with some FTP program.

Comment: Oke, I can publish the site now. I exude the bin folder from the project.

Comment: I get some other erros, I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I referenced some libraries (which had reference to another libraries) in my ASP.NET web application. Unfortunately after project rebuild dll's which were previously copied to bin folder were deleted. This caused publish problem very similar to your problem. Solution was to copy all needed files to bin folder. I guess you need to put your files back to bin folder and it will publish successfully.

Deleting bin folder is not an option - these files are needed;)